# Lowering carbs intake while increasing fat intake accordingly without compromising progress

Tags: bodybuilding

The standard recommendation regarding the respective proportions of macro intake conflicts with my food preferences: I prefer to eat more fat (in the form of butter and coconut/olive oil for example) and less carbs compared with the standard ratio.

Is it possible to increase fat intake by say 20-30% while decreasing carbs intake by the same percentage without compromising muscle mass gain progression?

Comment: I'm afraid this question falls outside the scope of the site. Questions on nutrition need to be angled towards physical exercise to be on-topic here. Also, it's hard to answer "can I do this?" type questions. Of course you can. What's stopping you?

Comment: It's a "can I" question only on the surface because I added "without compromising my progression?", I could have formulated otherwise by asking: "would tweaking macros this way compromise my progression?". Different wording but exact same question

Comment: Referring to coconut and olive oil interchangeably doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: Please explain why. Both are calorie sources and both are mostly fat aren't they?

Comment: (1) I explained that the question isn't of the "can I" type, (2)There are now 3 votes for reopening the question, and (3) I edited it to make sure it's correctly formulated. Can it be reopened now?